# sam local start-api - BinaryMediaTypes not working locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am running my AWS Lambdas locally using SAM and it's `sam local start-api -t template.yaml` command. Everything works fine apart from one of my Lambdas which is supposed to return an `application/pdf` binary media type. I have enabled this type of response in the template.yaml I am using to launch SAM.

Here is a snippest of the template.yaml showing this:

```
Resources:
  FrontendCertificateapilocalchild7173C752:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName: localhost:4000
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: localhost:4000
          ValidationDomain: localhost:4000
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: local/Frontend/Certificate-api-local-child
      ValidationMethod: EMAIL
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/Certificate-api-local-child/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      BinaryMediaTypes:
        - "*/*"
      Description: This service serves the frontend.
      Name: Frontend Service
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Resource
```

The response I get through Postman is however not formatted correctly and I get the following error message when the PDF response opens:

> Failed to load PDF file.

When I deploy the code to AWS it works absolutely fine, which is why I believe this is an issue with SAM.

I have posteda redacted version of my template.yaml in case that might help someone to see where I have gone wrong (sorry for the size, its the smallest I could make it). Any ideas?

Thanks

```
Resources:
  FrontendCertificateapilocalchild7173C752:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName: localhost:4000
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: localhost:4000
          ValidationDomain: localhost:4000
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: local/Frontend/Certificate-api-local-child
      ValidationMethod: EMAIL
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/Certificate-api-local-child/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      BinaryMediaTypes:
        - "*/*"
      Description: This service serves the frontend.
      Name: Frontend Service
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalCloudWatchRole66A87201:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: apigateway.amazonaws.com
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/CloudWatchRole/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalAccount3AC7EEFA:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Account
    Properties:
      CloudWatchRoleArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalCloudWatchRole66A87201
          - Arn
    DependsOn:
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Account
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalDeployment86803513d253457674c45cab7d651a56bf762787:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
      Description: This service serves the frontend.
    DependsOn:
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalOPTIONS37358616
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderOPTIONS93DCA01D
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidGET755A64B2
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidOPTIONS4050D92E
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidC7654574
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfOPTIONS25C6B290
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdf8ADB696B
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorder190D5B05
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Deployment/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalDeploymentStageprodBC56BC1F:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
      DeploymentId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalDeployment86803513d253457674c45cab7d651a56bf762787
      StageName: prod
    DependsOn:
      - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalAccount3AC7EEFA
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/DeploymentStage.prod/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalCustomDomainB4D30972:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
    Properties:
      DomainName: localhost:4000
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      RegionalCertificateArn:
        Ref: FrontendCertificateapilocalchild7173C752
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/CustomDomain/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalCustomDomainMaplocalFrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal22D5CF714E8C516E:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Properties:
      DomainName:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalCustomDomainB4D30972
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
      Stage:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalDeploymentStageprodBC56BC1F
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/CustomDomain/Map:--=>localFrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal22D5CF71/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalOPTIONS37358616:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      ResourceId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
          - RootResourceId
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'http://localhost:3000'"
              method.response.header.Vary: "'Origin'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "'true'"
            StatusCode: "204"
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: "{ statusCode: 200 }"
        Type: MOCK
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            method.response.header.Vary: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
          StatusCode: "204"
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/OPTIONS/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorder190D5B05:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
          - RootResourceId
      PathPart: order
      
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderOPTIONS93DCA01D:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      ResourceId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorder190D5B05
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'http://localhost:3000'"
              method.response.header.Vary: "'Origin'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "'true'"
            StatusCode: "204"
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: "{ statusCode: 200 }"
        Type: MOCK
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            method.response.header.Vary: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
          StatusCode: "204"
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/OPTIONS/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdf8ADB696B:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorder190D5B05
      PathPart: pdf
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/pdf/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfOPTIONS25C6B290:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      ResourceId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdf8ADB696B
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'http://localhost:3000'"
              method.response.header.Vary: "'Origin'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "'true'"
            StatusCode: "204"
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: "{ statusCode: 200 }"
        Type: MOCK
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            method.response.header.Vary: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
          StatusCode: "204"
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/pdf/OPTIONS/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidC7654574:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdf8ADB696B
      PathPart: "{id}"
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/pdf/{id}/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidOPTIONS4050D92E:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      ResourceId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidC7654574
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'http://localhost:3000'"
              method.response.header.Vary: "'Origin'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "'true'"
            StatusCode: "204"
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: "{ statusCode: 200 }"
        Type: MOCK
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            method.response.header.Vary: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
          StatusCode: "204"
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/pdf/{id}/OPTIONS/Resource
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidGETApiPermissionlocalFrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal22D5CF71GETorderpdfidEFB3D8F0:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - FrontendLambdasApilocalgetPdfOrderFunctionC0BB63A2
          - Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "arn:"
            - Ref: AWS::Partition
            - ":execute-api:us-east-1:"
            - Ref: AWS::AccountId
            - ":"
            - Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
            - /
            - Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalDeploymentStageprodBC56BC1F
            - /GET/order/pdf/*
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/pdf/{id}/GET/ApiPermission.localFrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal22D5CF71.GET..order.pdf.{id}
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidGETApiPermissionTestlocalFrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal22D5CF71GETorderpdfid601C4318:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - FrontendLambdasApilocalgetPdfOrderFunctionC0BB63A2
          - Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "arn:"
            - Ref: AWS::Partition
            - ":execute-api:us-east-1:"
            - Ref: AWS::AccountId
            - ":"
            - Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
            - /test-invoke-stage/GET/order/pdf/*
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/pdf/{id}/GET/ApiPermission.Test.localFrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal22D5CF71.GET..order.pdf.{id}
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidGET755A64B2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: GET
      ResourceId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalorderpdfidC7654574
      RestApiId:
        Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        ContentHandling: CONVERT_TO_TEXT
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/
              - Fn::GetAtt:
                  - FrontendLambdasApilocalgetPdfOrderFunctionC0BB63A2
                  - Arn
              - /invocations
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/ApiGateway-local/frontend-api-local/Default/order/pdf/{id}/GET/Resource
  FrontendLambdaExecRolelocal891E0151:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/AmazonRDSFullAccess
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoPowerUser
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/AmazonSESFullAccess
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      RoleName: lambdaExecRole
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/LambdaExecRole-local/LambdaExecRole-local/Resource
  FrontendLambdasApilocalgetPdfOrderFunctionC0BB63A2:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: AssetParametersf0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800cS3Bucket56CC0B0C
        S3Key:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - Fn::Select:
                  - 0
                  - Fn::Split:
                      - "||"
                      - Ref: AssetParametersf0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800cS3VersionKey001FD9B3
              - Fn::Select:
                  - 1
                  - Fn::Split:
                      - "||"
                      - Ref: AssetParametersf0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800cS3VersionKey001FD9B3
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - FrontendLambdaExecRolelocal891E0151
          - Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: "1"
      FunctionName: order_pdf_get-order-pdf
      Handler: index.handler
      MemorySize: 1024
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Timeout: 900
    DependsOn:
      - FrontendLambdaExecRolelocal891E0151
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/Frontend/LambdasApi-local/getPdfOrderFunction/Resource
      aws:asset:path: /home/ben/development-projects/feesio/feesio-infra-backend/cdk.out/asset.f0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800c
      aws:asset:is-bundled: true
      aws:asset:property: Code
  CDKMetadata:
    Type: AWS::CDK::Metadata
    Properties:
      Analytics: v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/11Q227CMAz9Ft5DNraJPXPR3mAV+4DKpKYYmqRK3CFU9d/ntFTr9nRuVuyTF/221M8zuMW5Ka7zio66/WIwVyVW3hoMTCcywGjBQYlBt5tfT21ObiI7BTWVQm5w1+0BI69qSjMTujLGN47VFuvK3y0KFXeiZHvZPzyQrbdAbg+29yZqDREz4PMO6ppcmdL/lqz1TTCYfLVDPvsijT3YmD4O7HmnCKyc7qvBFuxUBfZYgBQ/uQyDpRjJuxR/NM6w8HEkd77AS9T7HsZUxdccYkSOepVAtF435oqc7urSQ58N1w2rPk61H30yCNKUMfw9MW3Rl/j0vVjqxbtezC6RaB7kV8miPgz4A2efNcrZAQAA
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: local/CDKMetadata/Default
Outputs:
  FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalEndpointAFD88AF3:
    Value:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - https://
          - Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocal5C7648A5
          - .execute-api.us-east-1.
          - Ref: AWS::URLSuffix
          - /
          - Ref: FrontendApiGatewaylocalfrontendapilocalDeploymentStageprodBC56BC1F
          - /
Parameters:
  AssetParametersf0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800cS3Bucket56CC0B0C:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 bucket for asset "f0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800c"
  AssetParametersf0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800cS3VersionKey001FD9B3:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 key for asset version "f0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800c"
  AssetParametersf0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800cArtifactHash2F045658:
    Type: String
    Description: Artifact hash for asset "f0593e76148ddf4e25df024c8a632facbd1880dc86834ff2929fb4ce320e800c"
```